# How to target specific user role?

Tags: redirect, user-roles

I'm trying to place a simple bunch of codes to redirect the 'Subscribers' only, to the home page (or a desired page) after login. I thought to use `if( current_user_can('read') ):`, but that's a global capability, will be applicable for all the other roles too. So I tried `get_role('subscriber')`. Here are my `functions.php` codes (thanks to [Len](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-redirect-users-to-the-front-page-after-log-in)):

```
function subscriber_redirection() {
    global $redirect_to;
    if( get_role('subscriber') ) {
        if ( !isset( $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ) {
            $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
        }
    }
}
```

But it's redirecting the administrators too!

- **How can I target only a specific user role for a purpose?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_role`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role) is just going to return information about the role. It isn't going to tell you if the current user has that role. Use [`wp_get_current_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) with a check something like this:

```
function subscriber_redirection() {
    global $redirect_to;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array('subscriber',$user->roles)) {
        // user has subscriber role
        if ( !isset( $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ) {
            $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why you are using `global $redirect_to;` but never do anything with the variable.

Answer (score 2):

'get_role' returns an object, not a boolean: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role

```
// for example: if the user can not moderate comments
if (!current_user_can('moderate_comments') ) {

//redirect

}
```

You can find all capabilities here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities